# Making UIApplication(AppDelegate) embedded object

Tags: ios, object, delegates, appdelegate

Maybe my title was wrong, but I have no idea to explain now;

Embedded object in title means, such as `UINavigationController`.

If we made a navigation based project, the project was already set the navigation controller in AppDelegate, so we just can use it as `self.navigationController`.

Like this, I want to add some custom object to Application.
I want to use it as a application property such as `self.customObject`, not passing through `UIApplication` method.

How can I make it properly?

Thanks.

Comment: then you need to define object in .h file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just define it @properties in your app delegate

in .h file

if you define 
your object in { } it ll be use as local variable

if you define it as @properties

it ll be use by self.yourObject

or if you define it both area

you need to synthesize it